# gemfire entry timeout does not work when using data redundancy across multiple servers

Tags: timeout, gemfire

In Gemfire, my records should expire n seconds after the last time the record was read.
entry-idle-time seems to fit that description but I cannot get it to work.

I tried
gfe:entry-tti action="DESTROY" timeout="120"

This works fine when I have just one server, but when I have 2 servers with redundant copies = 1, my entries get removed even when my test program has been querying them every few seconds.

I tried action="LOCAL_DESTROY", but then the server does not start-up at all.

How can I get entries to stay alive as long as someone is querying them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the last modified time is only updated in in whichever copy the query goes to. The other copy then deletes the entry when it expires. If you run with redundancy 0, I think you will get the expiration behavior you expect.

The gemfire docs have a note about not using entry-idle-time with PRs, I think maybe for this reason:

"For partitioned regions, to ensure reliable read behavior, use the time-to-live attributes, not the idle-time attributes. In addition, you cannot use local-destroy or local-invalidate expiration actions in partitioned regions."

http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/latest/userguide/index.html#developing/expiration/configuring_data_expiration.html